Invalid hook call error on useEffect in a React component
I'm getting this error:
The fix was that I needed to change state differently- the way I was updating state for my player and dealer hand was wrong.
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

And am struggling to understand why, as useEffect is being used within my react component
Here are the atom definitions:
import { atom } from "jotai";

export const playerHandAtom = atom([]);
export const dealerHandAtom = atom([]);

I've combined all the code into one file for the sake of this question but the dealer functions will all be in a file dealer.js and be imported, but even when in the same component, I'm still getting the same issue. I'm not sure if it's a duplicate version of React issue?
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { useAtom } from "jotai";
import { playerHandAtom, dealerHandAtom } from "./atoms";
import board from "./img/table_with_chips.png";

const BlackJack = () => {
  const [dealerHand, setDealerHand] = useAtom(dealerHandAtom);
  const [playerHand, setPlayerHand] = useAtom(playerHandAtom);

  const deck = [
    ["2", 2],
    ["3", 3],
    ["4", 4],
    ["5", 5],
    ["6", 6],
    ["7", 7],
    ["8", 8],
    ["9", 9],
    ["10", 10],
    ["jack", 10],
    ["queen", 10],
    ["king", 10],
    ["ace", 11],
  ];

  const dealCard = (hand) => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    hand.push(deck[random][0]);
  };

  const dealHand = () => {
    const tempPlayHand = [];
    const tempDealHand = [];
    dealCard(tempPlayHand);
    dealCard(tempPlayHand);
    dealCard(tempDealHand);
    dealCard(tempDealHand);
    setPlayerHand(tempPlayHand);
    setDealerHand(tempDealHand);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dealHand();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="game-container">
      <img id="game-board" alt="Green Blackjack poker table" src={board} />
    </div>
  );
};


I tried downgrading my dependencies as it said mismatched versions could be the issue as well, but that didn't work and I want to keep it at React 18 or higher because I'm using createRoot.
Here are my current dependencies: 18.2.0 was recommended as it wasn't the most recent, but I'm still getting the same error.
"jotai": "^2.8.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.23.0"

Thanks all

Does dealHand use any react hooks for state management? If you include the dealHand method directly in this file does the error go away? Please include the definition of dealHand.

It does not- I changed my code so that everything is in a single file and still am getting the same error, and included the now whole code in this file. Thanks for your input

misuse of useAtom
You should not be calling useAtom again like that -
const BlackJack = () => {
  const [dealerHand, setDealerHand] = useAtom(dealerHandAtom);
  const [playerHand, setPlayerHand] = useAtom(playerHandAtom);
  
  const dealCard = (hand) => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    hand.push(deck[random][0]);
  };

  const dealHand = () => {
    // ❌ don't call useAtom here again
    // ❌ this function already has access to it
    dealCard(playerHand);
    dealCard(playerHand);
    dealCard(dealerHand);
    dealCard(dealerHand);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dealHand();
  }, []);

  // ...
};

illegal state modification
You have other problems though, hand.push is not how you modify state in react -
const BlackJack = () => {
  const [dealerHand, setDealerHand] = useAtom(dealerHandAtom);
  const [playerHand, setPlayerHand] = useAtom(playerHandAtom);
  
  const dealCard = (setHand) => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    // ❌ hand.push will not work
    // ✅ functional update
    setHand(hand => [...hand, deck[random][0]]);
  };

  const dealHand = () => {
    // ✅ pass setter instead
    dealCard(setPlayerHand);
    dealCard(setPlayerHand);
    dealCard(setDealerHand);
    dealCard(setDealerHand);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dealHand();
  }, []);

  // ...
};

card duplication
There is still work to go.  Currently if random is the same, the same card could be dealt multiple times. When we deal a card in blackjack, we remove it from the top of the deck and add it to the player's hand.
Let's use jotai write-only atoms to encapsulate this logic. We can customize the writer to take any value. In this example, the writer will take the number of cards to draw -
const deckAtom = ...
const dealerHandAtom = ...
const playerHandAtom = ...

const createDrawAtom = handAtom => atom(
  null,
  (get, set, count) => {
     // read current deck
     const deck = get(deckAtom)
     // add `count` cards to hand
     set(handAtom,  hand => [...hand, ...deck.slice(0, count)])
     // remove `count` cards from top of deck
     set(deckAtom, deck.slice(count))
  }
)

const dealerDrawAtom = createDrawAtom(dealerHandAtom)
const playerDrawAtom = createDrawAtom(playerHandAtom)

State transition logic is now removed from BlackJack component -
const BlackJack = () => {
  const [deck, setDeck] = useAtom(deckAtom)
  const [dealerHand] = useAtom(dealerHandAtom); // reader
  const [playerHand] = useAtom(playerHandAtom); // reader

  const dealerDraw = useSetAtom(dealerDrawAtom); // writer
  const playerDraw = useSetAtom(playerDrawAtom); // writer

  // initialize game
  useEffect(() => {
    dealerDraw(2) // ✅ 2 cards
    playerDraw(2) // ✅ 2 cards
  }, []);

  // ...
};

double draw
Even this has hidden issues if we're not careful to understand how effects work in React. Developing in StrictMode we would see that BlackJack does not properly cleanup, resulting in double draw. Again, a write-only atom can encapsulate the logic -
const newGameAtom = J.atom(
  null,
  (_get, set) => {
    // ✅ reset
    set(deckAtom, [...])
    set(dealerHandAtom, [])
    set(playerHandAtom, [])
    // ✅ draw 2 cards each
    set(playerDrawAtom, 2)
    set(dealerDrawAtom, 2)
  }
)

const BlackJack = () => {
  const newGame = J.useSetAtom(newGameAtom) // ✅ newGame writer
  
  R.useEffect(() => {
    newGame()
    // ✅ no worry about clean up
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>BlackJack</h1>
      <Deck />
      <PlayerHand />
      <DealerHand />
      <Buttons />
    </div>
  )
}

keep components simple
By limiting the amount of state a component "observes", we prevent it from redrawing unnecessarily -
const Deck = () => {
  const [deck] = J.useAtom(deckAtom)
  return <div>Deck: ({deck.length}) {JSON.stringify(deck)}</div>
}

const PlayerHand = () => {
  const [playerHand] = J.useAtom(playerHandAtom)
  return <div>
    <h2>Player: ({playerHand.length}) {JSON.stringify(playerHand)}</h2>
  </div>
}

const DealerHand = () => {
  const [dealerHand] = J.useAtom(dealerHandAtom)
  return <div>
    <h2>Dealer: ({dealerHand.length}) {JSON.stringify(dealerHand)}</h2>
  </div>
}

const Buttons = () => {
  const playerDraw = J.useSetAtom(playerDrawAtom)
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => playerDraw(1)}>Hit</button>
    <button onClick={() => alert("anticipate the score ...")}>Stand</button>
  </div>
}

explore jotai
Jotai offers other features to modify state during specific events. See onMount to shuffle the deckAtom when it's mounted to the component -
const shuffle = (deck) => ...

const deckAtom = atom(...)

deckAtom.onMount = (setAtom) => {
  setAtom(deck => shuffle(deck)) // ✅ shuffle on mount
}


This is the correct anwser

I would attempt pinning both versions to "18.2.0" without using the ^ sign, 18.3.1 is quite recent and there might be some patches coming soon
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",


I tried locking it at 18.2.0 for both without success
